How to register multiple implementations of an interface in ASP.NET Core without manual registration?
I am using C# and .NET 8 and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.
I have an interface that has 30+ different classes which are implementing it. I want to inject IEnumerable<MyInterface> into another class with a scoped lifetime.
I realize I am able to register each of the 30 classes manually - something like this:
services.AddScoped<MyInterface, MyConcreteClassOne>();
services.AddScoped<MyInterface, MyConreteClassTwo>();
...
services.AddScoped<MyInterface, MyConreteClassThirty>();

Is there a way to accomplish this in a more dynamic way that does not involve having to manually register each individual class?
EDIT: I found a solution that appears to work. Is somebody able to give me feedback?
Type baseClass = typeof(IBaseClass);
var types = Assembly.GetAssembly(baseClass)?.
GetTypes().Where(p => !p.IsAbstract && !p.IsInterface && baseClass
                .IsAssignableFrom(p));

foreach (Type t in types!)
{
   services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseClass), t);
}


You'd probably want to use Keyed services as otherwise every next registration will be overriding the previous one

@Kiryl, your statement is incomplete, because the example given by OP is the way in MS.DI to register collections. Nothing will be overridden here. The ServiceCollection is appended.

@Steven not sure I'm following... what is incomplete? If I do multiple registrations of the same base interface and then try to resolve it, I get just the last one, not an array. Do you get a different result?

@Kiryl: yes, in the context of this question, you'll get a different result, because OP is injecting "IEnumerable<MyInterface> into another class." In that case, calling AddScoped<MyInterface, ...>() multiple times will result in the injection of a collection of MyInterface instances containing all registered classes.

@Steven ah, I see now, missed the "IEnumerable" part. Thanks

The reflection solution is correct. Besides, you could try Scrutor https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor for easy assembly scanning.
var allowedServices = new[] { "MyConcreteClassOne", "MyConreteClassTwo", "MyConreteClassThirty" };

services.Scan(scan => scan
            .FromAssemblyOf<MyInterface>()
            .AddClasses(classes =>
                classes.AssignableTo<MyInterface>()
             //          .Where(type => allowedServices.Contains(type.Name))  //apply this filter to register specific service names
                       ) 
            .As<MyInterface>()
            .WithScopedLifetime());


I'm trying to implement assembly scanning in my ASP.NET Core project and found that Scrutor can be used for this purpose. Scrutor is an open-source library that adds assembly scanning capabilities to the ASP.NET Core DI container.
Here's the code I'm using to register my services:
public interface IScopedDependency
{
}

public interface ITransientDependency
{
}

public interface ISingletonDependency
{
}

public static void RegisterServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Scan(scan => scan
        .FromApplicationDependencies()
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<ITransientDependency>())
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .WithTransientLifetime()
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IScopedDependency>())
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .WithScopedLifetime()
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<ISingletonDependency>())
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .WithSingletonLifetime());
}

